# Flutter/Dart text input redirecting on second page rather than landing page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to get text to show on the front landing page that has the FloatingActionButton, rather than redirect the text input onto a new page. Can someone point out where I am going wrong? Any help is appreciated

Below is the code, I have removed the code the Class code that the FloatingActionButton is on the Class is Home Extends StatelessWidget:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      createAlertDialog(context);
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  ),
);
}


createAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
String value;
return AlertDialog(
  title: Text("Add RSS URL"),
  content: TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    onChanged: (text) {
      value = text;
    },
  ),

  actions: <Widget>[
    MaterialButton(
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: Text('Add'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dude(value)));
      },
    ),
       ],
      );
     },
    );
   }
   }

class URL extends StatefulWidget {
 final String text;

URL(this.text);

 @override
 _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
  }

  class _HomeState extends State<URL> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(widget.text),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're asking but your button opens a Modal Dialog which is a pop-up screen.

If you want to remain on the same screen, then get rid of the modal.

You want to use a combination of Visibility() which takes in a visibility: boolean parameter.

Let's say you declare bool _visibility = false;

When the user presses the FloatingActionButton, you want

```
onPressed: () => {setState(() { _visibility = !_visibility }); }
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Comment: And of course, you will need to refactor your home screen into a StatefulWidget to be able to use setState.

Comment: Sorry, @Kallis, this may have been a miss understanding. I want Modal FAB to display. I want the text to be inserted on the Home landing page in listview, rather than a new separate screen in the app. Currently the input is being printed on a whole new screen. Rather then the one with the FAB button on it.